# Collision filtering in libgdx using Liquidfun

Tags: libgdx, box2d, liquidfun

I successfully implemented liquidfun extension in my libgdx/box2d project, but the particles that are created in the box2d world doesn't seem to collide with anything at all when used in my project. The test code given with [the setup](https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension/wiki/Setup) works good in the way that it collides with the rigid bodies.

I actually want to know any way that collision filtering can be done between the particles and rigid bodies here. Apparently categorybits/maskbits do not work here. Please Help!